# How to subtract multiple similarly labeled columns from one another?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data set resembling the following:

[image]

I want to subtract the value of all Tuesdays from corresponding values of Mondays. So the resulting first column would be Monday_1 - Tuesday_1, second resulting column would be Monday_2 - Tuesday_2, and so on.

Here is what the resulting data frame would look like.

[image]

I would like to keep the names of the Monday columns the same and select out the Tuesday cols. My real data set is much wider than this so not having to manually subtract is much easier. Ideally I want a `dplyr` solution.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:7, Monday_1 = c(4L, 11L, 18L, 6L, 20L, 
5L, 12L), Monday_2 = c(20L, 3L, 20L, 12L, 1L, 10L, 15L), Monday_3 = c(14L, 
20L, 8L, 17L, 4L, 2L, 3L), Monday_4 = c(13L, 8L, 11L, 3L, 12L, 
14L, 17L), Tuesday_1 = c(1L, 14L, 7L, 16L, 2L, 6L, 12L), Tuesday_2 = c(10L, 
8L, 1L, 16L, 10L, 13L, 9L), Tuesday_3 = c(4L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 
9L, 12L), Tuesday_4 = c(12L, 18L, 3L, 18L, 6L, 11L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`s `summarize`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  summarize(id, across(starts_with("Monday")) - across(starts_with("Tuesday")))
  id Monday_1 Monday_2 Monday_3 Monday_4
1  1        3       10       10        1
2  2       -3       -5       11      -10
3  3       11       19       -1        8
4  4      -10       -4        9      -15
5  5       18       -9       -3        6
6  6       -1       -3       -7        3
7  7        0        6       -9        9
```

Answer (score 6):

using `across` gives you this easily:

```
df |> 
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with("Monday")) - across(.cols = starts_with("Tuesday"))) |> 
  select(id, starts_with("Monday"))
#>   id Monday_1 Monday_2 Monday_3 Monday_4
#> 1  1        3       10       10        1
#> 2  2       -3       -5       11      -10
#> 3  3       11       19       -1        8
#> 4  4      -10       -4        9      -15
#> 5  5       18       -9       -3        6
#> 6  6       -1       -3       -7        3
#> 7  7        0        6       -9        9
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @TarJae for pointing me to this.

We can use `dplyover::across2()`. If you want to keep the names `Monday_1` etc. then we need to set the `.names` argument to `{xcol}`, in this case the values of the `Monday_1` etc. columns get overwritten.

Further, if we want to keep the `id` column and drop all other "used" columns, we need to use `transmute(id = id, across2(...))`, since dplyover doesn't support yet the `.keep` argument in `dplyr::mutate`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover)

df %>%
  transmute(id = id,
            across2(starts_with("Monday_"),
                 starts_with("Tuesday_"),
                 ~ .x - .y,
                 .names = "{xcol}"))
#>   id Monday_1 Monday_2 Monday_3 Monday_4
#> 1  1        3       10       10        1
#> 2  2       -3       -5       11      -10
#> 3  3       11       19       -1        8
#> 4  4      -10       -4        9      -15
#> 5  5       18       -9       -3        6
#> 6  6       -1       -3       -7        3
#> 7  7        0        6       -9        9
```

If we want to create new names like `diff_1` etc. the trick is to use set the `.names` argument to `"diff_{suf}`" which says, "use the string `"diff_"` and append the common suffix of each variable pair `{suf}`.

With this the output names will be `diff_1`, `diff_2` etc.

```r
df %>%
  transmute(id = id,
            across2(starts_with("Monday_"),
                    starts_with("Tuesday_"),
                     ~ .x - .y,
                    .names = "diff_{suf}"))

#>   id diff_1 diff_2 diff_3 diff_4
#> 1  1      3     10     10      1
#> 2  2     -3     -5     11    -10
#> 3  3     11     19     -1      8
#> 4  4    -10     -4      9    -15
#> 5  5     18     -9     -3      6
#> 6  6     -1     -3     -7      3
#> 7  7      0      6     -9      9
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Thx to @TimTeaFan input:
improved code: using `.keep="unsued` removing the `select`row:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('Monday_'),
                ~ . - get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'Monday_', 'Tuesday_')), 
                .names = "{str_replace(.col, fixed('Monday'), 'diff')}")) %>% 
  select(contains(c("id", "diff")))
```

Here is an alternative `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('Monday_'),
                ~ . - get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'Monday_', 'Tuesday_')), 
                .names = "{str_replace(.col, fixed('Monday'), 'diff')}")) %>% 
  select(contains(c("id", "diff")))
```

```
  id diff_1 diff_2 diff_3 diff_4
1  1      3     10     10      1
2  2     -3     -5     11    -10
3  3     11     19     -1      8
4  4    -10     -4      9    -15
5  5     18     -9     -3      6
6  6     -1     -3     -7      3
7  7      0      6     -9      9
```

@TimTeaFan has a package `dplyover` which contains `across2` that should also work, but I can't implement it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover


df %>%
  mutate(across2(starts_with("Monday_"),
                 starts_with("Tuesday_"),
                 ~ .x - .y,
                 .names = "{diff}"))

#error:

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across2(...)`.
Caused by error in `across2_setup()`:
! Problem with `across2()`  input `.names`.
✖ Unrecognized glue specification `{...}` detected in `.names`.
ℹ `.names` only supports the following expressions: '{xcol}', '{ycol}', '{idx}' or '{fn}'.
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me to this. I added an answer to explain a litte. I short, we can only use a limited number of glue specifications in `across2()`s `.names` argument. You want to use `"diff"` as a regular string and not as glue specification `"{diff}"`. Instead we use `{suf}` to extract the common suffix of each variable pair.

Comment: You could also improve your `across()` approach by adding `.keep = "unused"` to your `mutate()` call and then we wouldn't need the call to `select()` in the last line :)

Comment: @TimTeaFan Thx for the explanation. I hope the day will come and I can I apply your `across2`. I will let you know. Meanwhile the explanation was very helpful!